# Do we still need to attach leading zeros to numbered files?

Tags: sorting

I want to create an archive of numbered files. The files should appear in the natural sequence of numbers, i.e.

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 ...

Once upon a time operating systems used to sort numbered files by digit position:

> 1 11 12 ... 2 20 21 22 ... 3 30 31 ...

To avoid this, you had to add leading zeros:

> 001 002 003 ...

This is awkward if you do not know the total number of files. You will either have to rename the files if you create more than you planned:

> ... 98 99 <- end of numbering system
> ... 098 099 100 101 ... <- rename to add more files

or have an excess of leading zeros to provide for an unknown future:

> 00000000000000000000000000000001 ...

Working with computers today, it *seems* as if they now sort in the natural sequence. But then maybe that is just a visual gimmick for a user viewing his or her files, while *internally* they are still sorted in a non-natural sequence and maybe processes **do not process files in the order the user expects**.

Therefore, I'd like to know:

## Are leading zeros still necessary for natural ordering today?

On which operating systems?
**And where does a lack of zeros cause problems and it what way?**

Answer (score 0):

the names of your files are not numerics but characters, so in character sort, 90 is naturally greater than 1521 : comparison begins on the first character, and so on.
To avoid this, the names of your files have to contain the date, like this : YYYYDDMM + a number on 5 or 6 digits, dépending on the number of files you will create each day
example : 201403100000001, 201403100000002 etc
Sorting your files will show the most ancients in first or last position